# Possible to retrieve an EWS token using getCallbackTokenAsync from office.js add-in on mobile?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to use the office.js getCallbackTokenAsync method through an Outlook add-in to get a token that can be used to call EWS on a mobile device (mobile here referring to the Outlook App on iOS and Android, not OWA in a mobile browser)?

I'm trying to get a token I can pass to the server so the server can make calls to EWS that are triggered by the add-in. This works on desktop as a call to getCallbackTokenAsync from an add-in by default returns an EWS compatible token. However on mobile I'm seeing that the token returned is an Outlook REST token by default. I've tried explicitly passing that as false but still getting the REST version of the token returned on mobile.

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: false }, callback)
```

- Outputs a V2 Rest token on mobile instead of V1 EWS token.

The documentation indicates the REST token should only come back if an option 'isRest' is passed on the call. This does not line up with what I'm seeing where the REST token is returned by default.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5#outlook-office-mailbox-getcallbacktokenasync-member(1)

Is it possible to get an EWS token through an Outlook add-in's Office-js library on mobile? If so, how?

Note: I had previously asked about this on a community call and it was indicated there this would work.

> *Does the add-in’s getCallbackTokenAsync work on mobile to get a token that can be used against EWS on the server for authentication as the add-in user?*
>
> Yes, this should work. We do have customers who have implemented a service middle tier to call EWS on environments not supporting REST (like Exchange 2013 on premise). You can also use that technique to use Microsoft Graph. This is all valid if your add-in is accessing Exchange 2013 on premise.

- https://pnp.github.io/blog/office-add-ins-community-call/2022-05-11/

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` works different in mobile than other version. It returns an REST-formatted ID by default.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api

You can then convert it to EWS ID with API below to retrieve the token.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-converttoewsid-member(1)

Comment: This is about the token returned from getCallbackTokenAsync, not the itemId. Though on that point it should be mentioned that convertToEwsId is not available on mobile and also that the itemId on mobile is in the immutable format so can't be converted using the logic from that implementation.

Comment: The EWS tokens are not supported on mobile.